# How to mock a specific date in jasmine tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

How can I mock the new Date() value without impacting the new Date(dob).getTime() value in my Jasmine tests?

`getYears = (dob) -> Math.floor((new Date() - new Date(dob).getTime()) / MS)`

I'm thinking I need to callFake on `spyOn(window, 'Date')` but this will affect both?

Comment: I suggest using `Date.now()` instead of `new Date()` to get the value you seek.

Comment: You mean instead of new Date() do Date.now()?

Comment: Yes. [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) returns a number, equivalent to `new Date().getTime()`.

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to use [sinon.useFakeTimers](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v1.17.6/fake-timers/) from the [Sinon.JS](https://sinonjs.org/) library to mock `Date`.

> Causes Sinon to replace the global setTimeout, clearTimeout, setInterval, clearInterval and Date with a custom implementation which is bound to the returned clock object.

```
var clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();

// your test code

// Restore to native Date
clock.restore();
```

Support for this seems also be available without Sinon.JS in [lolex](https://github.com/sinonjs/lolex)

> Fake setTimeout and friends (collectively known as "timers"). Useful in your JavaScript tests. Extracted from Sinon.JS

```
var fixedNowInMillis = 1566214687551; 
var clock = lolex.createClock(fixedNowInMillis);

// test code

clock.uninstall();
```